# how to detect what triggered PM2 watch restart

Tags: node.js, pm2

Is there some kind of debug option to find out which file exactly was changed and caused PM2 to restart when it's used with `--watch` key?

Comment: I think Grunt creates some temporary files (I'm using it to compile es6 code with Babel), this code does not belong to server (node) app, both directories (source and destination) are listed in `ignore_watch` option, but the server app restarts each time one of them is changed.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem - did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

At least in my version 4.5.5 it is quite simple - just show the logs. But the trick is that you should not show the log from the process itself. Therefore just execute `pm2 logs` without specifying the process.

What you will get is something like this:

```
PM2 | Change detected on path fallback-backend/logger/logfiles/info.log for app SmartProduction-Fallback - restarting
```